# Merge two tables with different structure into one

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

That is the structure of my original employees table .

This is the employees table from a different database that i want to be merged with my original employees table:
[image]

Its tricky because they have different structures. I was thinking of just adding the columns from the new employees table to the original employees table.

Comment: why is full name primary key OMG

Comment: @GGio I didn't make that. It was just from an open source Time Clock software from: http://timeclock.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I guess they dont have 2 John Smith

Comment: I would map any fields you can.  Then add the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i would do is drop both tables and create **NORMALIZED TABLES**. Right now both of the tables are not normalized and if you perform a lot of queries on these tables it will be slow.

Instead you can split both tables and get necessary info for example:

```
   Users Table Columns (ID, UserName, Password, CreateDate etc...)
   Users Info Table Columns (ID, FirstName, LastName, Gender, Age etc....)
   User Activation Table (ID, UserActive, ActivationDate, DeActivationDate etc.)
```

and use foreign keys to reference to ID from other 2 tables. Read up on **relational databasees**

Comment: Drop the table? I'm pretty sure that's not a great idea now since I dont have much time left and I didn't make this system so it might ruin the working php system. So I have no choice but to stick with the unnormalized tables. :(

Comment: then figure out which columns are used in PHP and merge them. FullName will not be necessary since you have first and last names in first table so find in PHP where it uses FullName and split to use First and Last names. P.S. DONT USE FullName as primary key

Comment: Would just adding the columns from the new employees table to my original employees table work? If so, how can i move those columns to the original employess table?